# Install Android APK on emulator using appium Node server

Tags: android, node.js, testing, appium-android

I have an appium server created in NODE.JS. I am working out to make the appium test to run an emulator and install the apk. Not able to find any particular examples online that has example on how to do it using Node server. Mostly examples are with the desktop installed appium server. I need some guidelines on how to do that. To further break it down, I want to perform following things using the appium Node server (Not to right any test case in the application source code)

1. Start the emulator or possible if can do it on real device
2. Install the APK on the emulator/device
3. Fire an intent that launches the app on emulator/device . Intent also contains data in bundle
4. Perform a click on a button inside the app.

Answer (score 0):

1. start appium server in your terminal

   `appium`
2. Output of above command like below on your terminal

[image]

3. Sample code here :

   public class AppTest {

   ```
   AppiumDriver driver;

   MobileElement appTitle;

   @Before
   public void setup() throws MalformedURLException {
       DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
       desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
       desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "7.0");
       desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, true);
       desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Moto");
       desiredCapabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "com.android.vending");
       desiredCapabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, "com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity");
       driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), desiredCapabilities);
   }

   @Test
   public void testGooglePlayApp() throws InterruptedException {
       String appName = "Amazon Now - Grocery Shopping";

       //How to scroll to specific text
       MobileElement scrollToText = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text(\"" + appName + "\"));"));
       scrollToText.click();

       // Verifying the app detail page
       appTitle = (MobileElement) driver.findElementById("com.android.vending:id/title_title");

       Assert.assertTrue(appName.equals(appTitle.getText().trim()));

       driver.navigate().back();

       //Clicking the search bar icon

       MobileElement scrollToElement = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().description(\"Search\"));"));
       scrollToElement.click();


       MobileElement editText = (MobileElement) driver.findElementById("com.android.vending:id/search_box_text_input");

       editText.sendKeys(appName);

       Thread.sleep(1000);

       List<MobileElement> listOfSuggestedResults = driver.findElementsById("com.android.vending:id/suggest_text");

       for (MobileElement element : listOfSuggestedResults) {
           if (appName.equals(element.getText().trim())) {
               element.click();
               break;
           }
       }

       appTitle = (MobileElement) driver.findElementById("com.android.vending:id/title_title");

       Assert.assertTrue(appName.equals(appTitle.getText().trim()));

   }

   @After
   public void tearDown() {
       if (driver != null) {
           driver.quit();
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Sample code in github : https://github.com/tech-tock-tech/apptest

hope above will help if you still facing issue please check below video link -

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jP2NAY8ylp8